# Why te conditional formatting rules doesn't work in excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

[image]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to do the conditional formatting for the percentage column which is more than 30%. However, it seems like highlighted all the cells for me even though it is a negative percentage. May I know why is it so?

Comment: Perhaps the cells are text representations.  What is the result of the formula `=ISNUMBER(cell_ref)` when excuted against each cell?

Comment: The answer is false, but I already formatted it to percentage, so what did I did wrong actually?

Comment: Seems like no matter what format I set, ISNUMBER() will always give me FALSE

Comment: Formatting does not change the data type.  What do you see in the formula bar when you select a cell?

Comment: I found a way to solve it already. I insert a value function to change the text to a number. Thanks for your remind and advise!

Comment: Glad to help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the cells are text representations. What is the result of the formula =ISNUMBER(cell_ref) when excuted against each cell?